# How to enable Reverse Proxy on F5

Tags: load-balancing, reverse-proxy, f5

I would like to know if the Virtual Servers + Pools setup in F5 is equal to Reverse Proxy enabled ? we have some web servers behind the F5 load-balancer with virtual server setup. but i am not sure if this is so call reverse proxy ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, this is the standard reverse proxy configuration. I cover the reverse proxy in [this video in our Whiteboard Wednesday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-tzXGiBAKU) series on youtube.